# scala native running demo

Tags: sbt, demo, scala-native

After successful building scala native trying to run the demo using following command

```
 cd scala-native
 sbt demoNative/run
```

which returns following error

```
/home/rimashm/.scalanative/rtlib-0.1-SNAPSHOT/rt.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'exception' file not found \#include <exception> 1 error generated. 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/rimashm/MITScriptTest/scala-native/demo/native/target/scala-2.11/demonative-out": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048) Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last demoNative/*:run for the full output. [error] (demoNative/*:run) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/rimashm/MITScriptTest/scala-native/demo/native/target/scala-2.11/demonative-out": error=2, No such file or directory [error] Total time: 16 s, completed Jun 7, 2016 4:58:18 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala Native contains a few lines of C++ code in https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native/blob/master/rtlib/src/main/resources/rt.cpp. Given your error message it seems that this part fails to compile. This might have been caused by missing headers for libc++.